# accept header setting in http get request

Tags: http, restsharp

I am using restsharp to consume a restful api. A code that used to work stopped working, apparently because I have to set 'accept headers' in my http get request. I understand that, according to some google searches, the accept header stuff is set by default by restsharp. So I obtained this http traffic via fiddler:

```
GET https://xxxx HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0
Host: test.nortechonline.net
Cookie: username=xxxx; auth_key=xxxx; ws_key=xxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Does this show that 'accept headers' is enabled?

Comment: Yes. There's an Accept: XXXXX header there. saying you'll accept most flavors of json, xml and javascript as responses. If you look here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html It'll show you more detail about the Accept header.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's an Accept: XXXXX header there. saying you'll accept most flavors of json, xml and javascript as responses. If you look here: w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html It'll show you more detail about the Accept header.